# Math.round / Divide problem with a long value

Tags: java, rounding, long-integer

I have a problem with dividing a long value by 1000 and round it to an integer.

My long value is: 1313179440000

My code is

```
long modificationtime = 1313179440000;
Math.round(modificationtime/1000l)
```

If i print out the divided and formated value, it returns me:
1313179392

so.

```
value   : 1313179440000
expected: 1313179440
got     : 1313179392
```

I do not know why this happens.
Can anybody help me?

best regards,
prdatur

Comment: That won't actually compile; what does your code actually look like?

Comment: add a `l` to the end of `1313179440000` so it is interpreted as a long value

Comment: @pst Does it depend on the compiler? Mine just gives an error on that line.

Comment: @ratchet freak You're correct. That's what I get from switching languages.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Math.round(float)` is being used. A float has a larger *range* than a long, but it cannot represent all integers within that range -- in this case the integer 1313179440 (the *original result* of the division) lies in the part of the range that exceeds integer precision.

1. Don't use `Math.round` as it's not needed (input is already an integer!), or;
2. Use `Math.round(double)`, as in: `Math.round(modificationTime/1000d)`. Note that the divisor is a double and thus the dividend (and the result) of the expression are also promoted to double.

Happy coding.

Comment: thanks, that helped.
I'm a bit php petted, so there i do not need to think about those things. :)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you get that result is that `Math.Round()` accepts either a `double`. Since your number isn't exactly representable as a `double`, the closest number that *is* gets passed in.

Note that `round()` is completely unnecessary here. `modificationTime/1000l` requires no rounding. If you *do* require rounding, change the argument to `modificationTime/1000d`.